# Ansible adding a rest api key to a get request

Tags: rest, ansible, yaml

I am a network engineer that has become the accidental admin of an ansible based network automation platform and am struggling with my limited knowledge to add an api key to a rest api get request.

I've been given a key to use, for example fake-api-key:1234567890 and I've tried adding it to the header of my API get call as per below -

```
- name: RETRIEVE SOMETHING
  uri:
    url: "https://host.name-api.com/service123/request?foo_bar={{ foobar}}"
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "fake-api-key/1234567890"
  register: foo
  when: bar
```

I am getting an "Error 401: Access Denied". However when I test it using postman it works, so it appears that the format is not correct in the YAML file. I've tried a few variations. It's probably something simple.

Can anyone who knows ansible please help identify what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you send wrong header. Is it really `Content-Type`? Maybe `API-Token` or something?

Comment: Or maybe try: `HEADER_Authorization: "fake-api-key/1234567890`.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in replying. So as some have pointed out, the correct answer is the following syntax

```
- name: RETRIEVE THIS CHANGE DETAIL
  uri:
    url: "https://some-url/service123/request?variable={{var}}}"
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    headers:
       fake-api-key: "1234567890"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is working in postman, please check the headers you are passing in postman. You can click on the Code link in the postman request builder to see all headers. Some will not be visible in the Headers tab (Eg. cache-control). Add all those headers to your request.

Comment: Hi There, I just realised this myself (Total newby to postman). Using this method I can see how the code is added, and I can also see from the debugs when I run the ansible-playbook the code ansible is interpreting the YAML file as. So I spotted the discrepancy, and I believe this may be resolved but as luck would have it the server I am targeting is down so will have to wait until I can test to confirm fix. I will post here when I've done that. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure :) Please let me know if need any further help with this. Also, mark this as answered if everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
headers:
  fake-api-key: 1234567890
```

This is the equivalent of `curl`

```
curl -X GET 'https://your_url' -H "fake-api-key:1234567890"
```